# Connecting an AB phase encoder motor to arduino

Tags: motor

i'm trying to understand how to connect this motor:

"Mitsumi 334P/R AB"

[Link to the motor i bought](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mitsumi-334P-R-AB-phase-encoder-encodes-tacho-motor-speed-disk-DC3V-24V-5V-6V-/221702525894?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item339e8013c6)

[image]

connections are:

GND - Obvious.

5v - Obvious.

rest of the connections are a bit confusing to me and i do not want to fry my arduino trying.

- do i need a driver or this looks like a built in one?
- do i need to add any electrical components like resistors and capacitors ect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a regular motor, with a (optical) rotary encoder inside. So the first two `motor` pins are to run the motor. So connect to VCC and GND, or GND and VCC, if you want to run it in reverse. (VCC doesn't have to be 5v; it can be 3v to 30v).

Connect A and B to a digital input pin. You can see what kind of signal you can expect in the screenshot of the oscilloscope, attached to the ebay-listing. So you can measure the speed, and relative position of the motor-shaft.

Comment: is there a way to decide (like stepper motor) to rotate 200 right/left? or this is a different kind that only measures speed and rotations?

Comment: You can turn on the motor, measure how many steps it's making, and turn off the motor when you reach 200 "steps". This is however grossly oversimplified, as in reality, due to inertia, you will probably overshoot these 200 steps. You probably need to slow down the motor (using PWM), when it's closing in on 200. Some kind of PID control.